# Managing QMainwindow and its subwindows

Tags: qt

I have a program in Qt creator. In this program the main widget is an image viewer and 4 other widget are displayed in this main widget. 
An overview of Software is available in this [link](http://s5.picofile.com/file/8119389542/Project.png)
How can i arrange this widgets in my image viewer program as shown in the picture?

Comment: You want to do it in designer or via code?

Comment: Why don't you try horizontal layout?

Answer (score 0):

Well i haven't worked with the QtCreator so far but if you want to set the size and position of a widget you call

```
my_qwidget->setGeometry(int x, int y, int w, int h);
```

as stated in the [Reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#geometry-prop)

Comment: thanks for your request,i use this but i cant change geometry of my widgets.

Comment: What to you mean with `you can't`? Do you get an error or does nothing happen? How do you implement it? Please edit your original question so it includes the relevant lines of your code.

Comment: I implement this program by code. when i add a HBoxlayout and insert widgets to this layout and run the program, aren't display widgets in the mainwindow

Comment: Please edit your original question so it includes the relevant lines of your code.